# mv files to a different path which is constructed via a regex replacement

Tags: find, regular-expression, rename

I have a directory full of files stored in subdirectories according to their filename, i.e.:

```
20d1/d325/52d1/20d1d32552d1a95249e62662fbdf924dd72c4027.jpg
ccaf/13cf/3199/ccaf13cf319930e80f5f2ad02525b93e1326c160.jpg
ec07/53bd/2355/ec0753bd2355fa8ec5cf5163e219c162cce3b03a.jpg
...
```

As you can see, the first 12 characters of the filename are used to create three levels of subdirectories. Unfortunately four characters per directory name were chosen, and as it happens the amount of files has grown beyond the directory limit of 32000 entries per directory on the filesystem. So they need to be rewritten to:

```
20d/1d3/255/2d1/20d1d32552d1a95249e62662fbdf924dd72c4027.jpg
cca/f13/cf3/199/ccaf13cf319930e80f5f2ad02525b93e1326c160.jpg
ec0/753/bd2/355/ec0753bd2355fa8ec5cf5163e219c162cce3b03a.jpg
...
```

So three letters per directory instead of four. There are a ton of files, so the process should be as fast as possible.

I have dabbled around with `find`:

```
find /path/to/files -mindepth 4 -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex \
".*/([0-9a-f]{4}/){3}(([0-9a-f]{3})([0-9a-f]{3})([0-9a-f]{3})([0-9a-f]{3})[0-9a-f]+\.\w+)"
```

This prints all the files nicely, but I'm not sure how to proceed with the rewriting. I'd like to use the regex capture groups in the rewrite process to rewrite the path to `$3/$4/$5/$6/$2` (backreferences to `find` regex). But `find` doesn't seem to support something like:

```
find ... -exec cp {} /elsewhere/$3/$4/$5/$6/$2 ;
```

What is the best approach to handle this? Some combination of `sed` and `xargs` (I'm not very experienced with those)? Should I go for a loop instead of a `find` action? I'm a little lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For copying the files you could use a combination of find and GNU tar for the job:

```
$ find -type f ... -print0 \
    | tar -c -f - --null --files-from - \
    | tar -C DEST_BASE -v -x -f - \
        --show-transformed \
        --transform 's,PATTERN,REPLACE,OPTIONS
```

(find generates all source file name, the first tar reads them into a pipe and the 2nd tar does the filename/path transformation)

By default the `--transform` option expects a basic regular expression, but there is also the `x` regexp-option available. Another useful regexp-option is `i` for case-insensitive matching.

Comment: See also `pax -rw -'s,PATTERN,REPLACE,'` for the POSIX equivalent.

Comment: Nice, that sounds like the way to go. I'll experiment with that.

Comment: @deceze Note that this copies the file, it doesn't move them. You can add `--remove-files` to the first `tar` invocation, but if anything happens (e.g. power failure), those files will be destroyed.

Comment: @Gilles That's actually fine, my plan is to copy the files into a different directory first, validate that all are present and then replace the old ones anyway; so this works just fine.

Comment: ...and while I was updating the sudoers file to give the migration user enough rights to do this, I foobar'd the visudo call somehow and locked myself out of the server completely. So now everything's set up from scratch on a different server and there's no need for this anymore; it was just a test server anyway (that's what you have test servers for). But thanks. :-D

Answer (score 2):

For moving you can use [`mmv`](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/mmv):

```
$ mmv -n ';????????????*.jpg' '#2#3#4/#5#6#7/#8#9#10/#11#12#13/#14.jpg'
20d1/d325/52d1/20d1d32552d1a95249e62662fbdf924dd72c4027.jpg
    -> 20d/1d3/255/2d1/a95249e62662fbdf924dd72c4027.jpg
ccaf/13cf/3199/ccaf13cf319930e80f5f2ad02525b93e1326c160.jpg
    -> cca/f13/cf3/199/30e80f5f2ad02525b93e1326c160.jpg
ec07/53bd/2355/ec0753bd2355fa8ec5cf5163e219c162cce3b03a.jpg
    -> ec0/753/bd2/355/fa8ec5cf5163e219c162cce3b03a.jpg
```

(-n is just for reporting and testing - files are not actually moved yet)

Unfortunately, `mmv` does not have a 'create-missing-directories' option - thus, we have to do it before the actual moving:

```
$ mmv -n ';????????????*.jpg' '#2#3#4/#5#6#7/#8#9#10/#11#12#13/#14.jpg' \
    | sed 's,^.* -> \(.*/\)[^/]\+$,\1,' \
    | xargs mkdir -p
```

`mmv` uses shell wildcards - not regexp. The `;` character is special and matches the source file base path . Backreferences are denoted via `#n`. Since shell wildcard are not as powerful as extended regexp I used 12 `?` wildcards to match the first 12 characters of the filename.

Comment: Sounds like the utility I need, but it's not installed by default and I'd like to stick to standard utilities where possible. Nice alternative to know about though.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a lot of files, you need to watch out for the command line length limit. Also, for performance reasons, you'd better not start a new process for each file.

Don't copy the files — that would take a huge amount of time, would double the disk space, and then you'd have the problem of deleting the originals without deleting the copies. Move the files, it's a lot more reliable.

While this can be done with shell utilities, it's a lot easier to write a robust and efficient script in Perl or Python or Ruby. You won't run into quoting issues or into the need to split command lines.

Perl (with error checking omitted on directory removal):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
for my $dir1 (<*>) {
    for my $dir2 (<$dir1/*>) {
        for my $dir3 (<$dir2/*>) {
            for my $file (<$dir3/*>) {
                $file =~ m:.*/((...)(...)(...)(...).*):;
                mkdir "$1";
                mkdir "$1/$2";
                mkdir "$1/$2/$3";
                mkdir "$1/$2/$3/$4";
                rename $file, "$1/$2/$3/$4/$file" or die "$file: $!";
            }
            rmdir $dir3;
        }
        rmdir $dir2;
    }
    rmdir $dir1;
}
```